# Razor Pages routing techniques

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, razor-pages

I'm new to razor pages (used to MVC pattern). I came across some interesting routing pattern I saw on GitHub:

```cs
services.AddMvc()
    .AddViewLocalization()
    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization()
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Edit", "/{Slug}/Edit");
        options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Delete", "{Slug}/Delete");
        options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Details", "{Slug?}");
        options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Details", @"Index");
        options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Create", "{Slug?}/Create");
    });
```

In some projects, I don't see the `AddRazorPagesOption`

Just out of curiosity, what would happen if I didn't specify routing like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `options.Conventions.AddPageRoute` just help you to define custom routing for your pages. So, the razor page:

1. `Edit` will have route template `/{Slug}/Edit` where `Slug` is a parameter from the URL.
2. `Delete` will have route template `/{Slug}/Delete` where `Slug` is a parameter from the URL.
3. `Details` will have route template `/{Slug?}` where `Slug` is a **optional** parameter from the URL.  Also you can go to that page using `/Index`.
4. `Create` will have route template `/{Slug?}/Create` where `Slug` is a optional parameter from the URL.

If you remove them all your razor pages will just use the defaut conventions which is folder base convention started the `Pages` folder as the root folder. For pages that have parameters you should pass them as query parameter in your request URL. For example without the conventions defined you'll have to use `/Edit?slug=myValue` if you want to go to the `Edit` page of `myValue` item. With the convention configured, the URL is pretty because you'll use `/myValue/Edit`.

I think the configuration you actually have is just here to avoid having parameters of your razor pages to be passed as query parameter in your request URL.